# Проблема с регистром css классов в jsp

Tags: java, css, классы, java-ee

Есть дав блока:

```css
.content {
  padding-top: 9px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="ConteNt">
  1
</div>

<div class="content">
  2
</div>
```

У класса `.content` прописаны стили в css файле:

Но проблема в том что эти же стили применяются и к классу `.ConteNt`.

Хотя они по разному написаны. При чем если брать чисто верстку то там такого нет.

Веб сервер `Tomcat 8`. html находится на `jsp` странице.

В чем может быть беда?

Comment: А причём тут JSP и Tomcat? CSS применяется браузером.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ибо в обычной верстке все работает в том же браузере, а когда запускается все на вебсервере с jsp результат другой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в первую строку страницы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Элемент  предназначен для указания типа текущего документа — DTD (document type definition, описание типа документа). Это необходимо, чтобы браузер понимал, как следует интерпретировать текущую веб-страницу, поскольку HTML существует в нескольких версиях.

Подробносит можете найти тут: http://htmlbook.ru/html/%21doctype